# If <video> then don't play on mobile

Tags: html, video, mobile, html5-video

I have a HTML5 page using `<video>` tag and running .webm files. It all works quite smoothly.

However, I would like to not run the video on mobile devices and instead replace it with the .jpeg poster.

This is the setup now:

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" poster="video1.jpg" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video1.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the video-tags via media-queries and "display:none;" and then replace it with a for desktop hidden img-tag.

Sorry for the short answer... Written with my mobile ;) I'll update the answer as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Most phones and tablets by default do not play video automatically, you will need to add a static background as a fallback for mobile devices.

https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/